# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this code:

```
ANZ=`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT count(id) FROM $TABLE WHERE deleted=1 and not lastname='anonym';" --skip-column-names -B;`;
if [ $((ANZ)) -gt 0 ]
then
mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT id, username FROM $TABLE WHERE deleted=1 and not lastname='anonym' and username like '%@%';" --skip-column-names -B > $FILE;

cat $FILE | while read TMP

do
echo "temp:" ${TMP%   *};

    UserID=${TMP%   *};
    echo $UserID >> $RES_FILE;

    echo "User $UserID wird anonymisiert...";
echo $UserID;

echo '`mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', dep$
echo'        `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message SET subject='Neue Mitteilung von anonym' WHERE useridfrom=$UserID;"`';
echo'        `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message_read SET subject='Neue Mitteilung von anonym' WHERE useridfrom=$UserID;"`';
    VNAME=`mysql -N -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT firstname FROM $TABLE WHERE id=$UserID;"`;
   NNAME=`mysql -N -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "SELECT lastname FROM $TABLE WHERE id=$UserID;"`;
     `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_event SET name='Meeting with your Student, anonym' WHERE name LIKE 'Meeting with your Student,%$VNAME $NNAME%';"`;

done
echo
"Finish!"
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="anonym611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291", email=a@nonym.de, firstname=anonym, lastname=anonym, icq=, skype=, yahoo=, aim=, msn=, phone1=, phone2=, institution=, department=, address=, city=, country=, url= WHERE deleted=1 AND id=611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291;"
>   ./anonym.sh: Zeile 50: echo
>   mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message SET subject=Neue: command not found.
>   ./anonym.sh: Zeile 52: echo        `mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE mdl_message_read SET subject=Neue: command not found.
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'demo@xxxxxxx.de.1456411291' at line 1
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right     syntax to use near 'demo@xxxxxxxxxx.de.1456411291' at line 1

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql error is here :

```
[...] WHERE deleted=1 AND id=611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291;"
```

You either need to close sql query right after `id=611` or maybe your id is `611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291`, in this case you need to add `"` around it.

Edit after @Bern Buffen answer :

You need to escape every `"` in your query :

```
echo 'mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username=\"$A$UserID\", email=\"a@nonym.de\", firstname=\"$A\", lastname=\"$A\", icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id=\"$UserID\";"';
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your Help,

Comment: my code is:echo '`mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', dep$
and after runnung skript a got this one:[...] WHERE deleted=1 AND id=611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291;"

Comment: i am so sorry .i mean this code: echo '`mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id='$UserID';"`';
 please help me.

Comment: i changed my code to :echo 'mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username=\"$A$UserID\", email=\"a@nonym.de\", firstname=\"$A\", lastname=\"$A\", icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id=\"$UserID\";"';  but unfortunatly i got error again.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use Quirles in a Quoted String . Use Single Quotes or escape it with backslash

="anonym611 demo@XXXXX.de.1456411291"

Comment: many thanks.you mean in this code:'mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWD -h$HOST -D $DATABASE -e "UPDATE $TABLE SET username="'$A$UserID'", email='a@nonym.de', firstname='$A', lastname='$A', icq='', skype='', yahoo='', aim='', msn='', phone1='', phone2='', institution='', department='', address='', city='', country='', url='' WHERE deleted=1 AND id='$UserID';"`';
what shall i do?please help me.i am new in Sql and PHP.